# Does the firebase initialisation code for javascript projects need to be run on each web page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Google login with fireauth. 
So in the login page i've got the following setup code in script tags:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

But then on subsequent pages I want access to firebase so i can check auth, use storage, etc.

To access firebase on subsequent pages do I need to run the above code again? Or is it best to put the iniitialisation code in an external javascript file so that i have access across all webpages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Firebase web apps are so-called single-page applications, which means that they're just one big HTML + JavaScript page. So they only need this block once in that page.

But if your web app depends on multiple separate HTML + JavaScript pages, you indeed will need this block on each page that uses Firebase. If you're using modern JavaScript you can isolate this block into a module that you include into the others. Or you can get it from `__/firebase/init.js`, which is automatically available if you're hosting the web site on Firebase. For more on this, see [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html), and [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#sdk_imports_and_implicit_initialization)

Comment: Thanks Frank. Just wondering why firebase web apps in particular are "single page" applications?

Comment: I don't know if there's a single reason, but I think the fact that you have to initialize Firebase in every page probably contributes. It works fine with multiple pages. It just seems cleaner and faster combining those views into a single page.